# For loop error: Tag Times is Protected

Tags: procedural-programming

i want to use For loop into my analytical physics theory but my For loop is not working.?
so please help me .here is my simple (for example code)

```
For[n = 1, n < Ns, n++
    Ns=100;
    dtr = π/180;
    χv = 7.2*dtr;
    χ = N[ArcTan[a*Tan[χv]]];
    i = χ*n;
    Print[i]
    ]
```

it returns the error

> `Set::write: Tag Times in 0.125664 1 is Protected. >>`

one more thing can we evaluate i without the command Print.?

Comment: There is a `,` missing after `n++`.

Comment: Also make sure `Ns` is set to a value before evaluating the `For` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Corrected code:

```
With[{Ns = 100}, For[n = 1, n < Ns, n++,
  dtr = π/180;
  χv = 7.2*dtr;
  χ = N[ArcTan[a*Tan[χv]]];
  i = χ*n;
  Print[i]]
 ]
```

Alternative code:

```
Module[{dtr = π/180, χv, χ, Ns = 100 - 1},
 χv = 7.2*dtr;
 χ = N[ArcTan[a*Tan[χv]]];
 Table[χ*n, {n, 1, Ns}]
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortening your coding and assigning a value to `a`

```
Ns = 3;
a = 2;

x = N[ArcTan[a*Tan[7.2*Pi/180]]]
```

> 0.247479

```
For[n = 0, n < Ns, n++ ; Print[x*n]];
```

now prints 3 values which you can more easily obtain with

```
x*Range[Ns]
```

> {0.247479, 0.494959, 0.742438}